# Pycuda CompileError with Anaconda on Windows

Tags: windows, compilation, cuda, anaconda, pycuda

I've just started looking into Cuda and especially PyCuda. I'm currently using Anaconda on Windows 7. I have installed Pycuda using the Anaconda Prompt and tried the following code, which I copied directly from the PyCuda documentation web page. However I've got an CompileError. Does anyone have any suggestion?

```
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as drv
import numpy

from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
mod = SourceModule("""
__global__ void multiply_them(float *dest, float *a, float *b)
{
  const int i = threadIdx.x;
  dest[i] = a[i] * b[i];
}
""")

multiply_them = mod.get_function("multiply_them")

a = numpy.random.randn(400).astype(numpy.float32)
b = numpy.random.randn(400).astype(numpy.float32)

dest = numpy.zeros_like(a)
multiply_them(drv.Out(dest), drv.In(a), drv.In(b), block=(400,1,1),grid(1,1))

print(dest-a*b)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-06c8e60d26ae>", line 12, in <module>
    """)

  File "C:\Users\Moritz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pycuda\compiler.py",         line 291, in __init__
    arch, code, cache_dir, include_dirs)

  File "C:\Users\Moritz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pycuda\compiler.py",    line 255, in compile
    return compile_plain(source, options, keep, nvcc, cache_dir, target)

  File "C:\Users\Moritz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pycuda\compiler.py",   line 137, in compile_plain
    stderr=stderr.decode("utf-8", "replace"))

CompileError: nvcc compilation of C:\Users\Moritz\AppData\Loca \Temp\tmpst8z9hvc\kernel.cu failed
```

Comment: The only error in this code is a missing `=` in the kernel launch argument. Otherwise it runs without error- Are you certain that you actually have a working CUDA and PyCUDA installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved the Problem. I've only had "Microsoft Visual Studio Express" installed, which, as it seems, does not support compiling 64bit applications. However, I've been running a 64bit Version of Anaconda on my PC. Installing Anaconda 32bit instead fixed the issue.

Comment: please remember to come back in a few days and accept this answer so that this question falls off the unanswered list for the CUDA tag